# How do I create a function that scrolls up the page bit-by-bit, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I create a function like this that scrolls up the page bit-by-bit?

```
$('#down').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top += 20
    });
    return false;
});
```

This function works for scrolling down the page...I've a play trying to get it to scroll up the page but no success.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: so you want to say that -=20 doesnt work ?

Comment: @Senad - Its totally weird because I thought the exact same thing but it doesn't work????

Comment: shouldn't it be `$(this).offset().top + 20`? also i wouldn't animate body and html simultanously as you'll get weird results

Comment: @Andy - I just had a go at implementing your solution & it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.pageYOffset will get you what you desire!

```
$('#up').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: window.pageYOffset -= 20
    });
    return false;
});
```

Have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGwJs/2/  Scroll down to the "up" link then keep clicking it.

Did some cross-browser testing on my code, found that it doesn't work for IE7, 8.  See this link here for making it jive on the old browsers: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Comment: Awesome.  Be sure to see my edit about cross-browser compatibility if that's a concern for you.

Answer (score 1):

from [here](http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery)

```
$('#down').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
}
```

2nd:

```
$('#up').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: 0
    }, 2000);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: see the thing is I need `#up` function just to scroll the window...not to any specific location...just scroll up a bit when the user click `#up`

Comment: Just scroll to 0 value :) or any other that you want